# Dir diff and removal

Tags: directory

Is there a simple way to (recursively) remove all files from a directory A that are identical  (same name and same hash) to files in directory B while preserving the structure?

e.g. A/file1 gets removed if B/file1 exists; but A/file1 gets not removed although B/d/file1 exists

Comment: You can use programs to find duplicated files like [duff](http://duff.sourceforge.net/) and then parse their output (instead of hardlink them).

Comment: if `python` is fine then see http://codeidol.com/community/python/comparing-directory-trees/17542/#part-11

Answer (score 1):

If you want all files in A to exist in B then you could simply use `rsync` with the `--remove-source-files` option, to add / update the files in B, with those in A, and then delete the original files from A. Or with a bit more hacking, running `rsync` in `--dry-run` mode, and piping the output through `grep`, `xargs` and `rm -f`, only compare the two directory structures, and delete the identical files, see:

[Linux / Unix rsync: Delete Source File After Transfer](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-appleosx-rsync-delete-file-after-transfer/)

[rsync --remove-source-files deletes source files one by one or after rsync completes?](https://superuser.com/questions/405761/rsync-remove-source-files-deletes-source-files-one-by-one-or-after-rsync-compl)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Please note this is untested code. I assume $A and $B are your two directories:

```
(cd $B && find . -type f -print) | (cd $A && while read f; do /bin/rm -f "${f}"; done;)
```

I just tried it, but echoing the command to stdout instead of running it, and it appears to work ok:

```
$ (cd $B && find . -type f -print) | (cd $A && while read f; do echo /bin/rm -f "${f}";done;)
/bin/rm -f ./1
/bin/rm -f ./2
/bin/rm -f ./3
/bin/rm -f ./4
```

If that appears to do what you want, run it again but omit the word "echo" in the command.